# cephadm set cluster_network

Tags: linux, storage, openstack, ceph

I have setup new cluster on single NIC using `cephadm` but i have added extra nic for replication `cluster_network`. This is what i did to configure cephadm but it didn't work.

`$ ceph config set global cluster_network 192.168.1.0/24`

View config

```
$ ceph config get mon cluster_network
192.168.1.0/24
$ ceph config get mon public_network
10.73.3.0/24
```

Validate

```
$ ceph osd metadata 1 | grep addr
    "back_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6812/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6813/1317996473]",
    "front_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6810/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6811/1317996473]",
    "hb_back_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6816/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6817/1317996473]",
    "hb_front_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6814/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6815/1317996473]",
```

Restarted using daemon

`$ ceph orch restart osd.1`

Still no impact

```
$ ceph osd metadata 1 | grep back_addr
    "back_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6812/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6813/1317996473]",
    "hb_back_addr": "[v2:10.73.3.191:6816/1317996473,v1:10.73.3.191:6817/1317996473]",
```

Comment: Did you also try to reconfigure the daemon or just restart (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763230/configure-a-cluster-network-with-cephadm).

Answer (score 0):

try reconfiguring daemons

```
ceph orch daemon reconfig mon
ceph orch daemon reconfig osd
```

if the issue persist you should run this command

`cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip <public_ip> --cluster-network <inetranl_ip_range>`

Comment: Is it safe to run bootstrap in production? I thought bootstrap for initial cluster setup.

Comment: well i haven't done this before i don't think it wipe osds but don't run it in production env. test in lab before you do this if you only have rbd pools you can migrate them easily to new cluster.
did you try re-configuring ?